# How can I specify the memory that cpu will use?

Tags: memory, cpu, gem5

In gem5 simulator, how can i specify the memory that cpu will use like picture?

I want to make a situation that cpu0 only uses a DRAM, cpu1 only uses a NVM.

Is it possible?
[image]

Comment: Please help me..

Comment: Hi, double check your image as it did not show up. If the CPUs will have different memories, what will be the link between them? Also ask on the mailing list.